# Flask-socketio как передать параметры порта и ip

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, flask, python-3.5

Раньше не использовал socketio,сейчас начал. Тогда я в `app.run` передавал параметры, а теперь мне его нужно заменять на         `socketio.run(app)`
Как туда передать параметры для app?

Answer (score 0):

Я запускаю как прежде, через `app.run()`, а вот там где нужно `socketio` инициализирую его таким образом:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet', logger=True, engineio_logger=True)

@socketio.on('test_sio')
def test_sio(message):
    print([{i: message[i]} for i in message])
    emit('test_connection', {'data': rooms()})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=4321, debug=True)
```